# Leads to find tables correlation

Tags: algorithm, correlation, apriori

Have these two tables:

```
TableA
ID  Opt1    Opt2    Type
1   A       Z       10
2   B       Y       20
3   C       Z       30
4   C       K       40
```

and

```
TableB
ID  Opt1    Type
1   Z       57
2   Z       99
3   X       3000
4   Z       3000
```

What would be a good algorithm to find arbitrary relations between these two tables? In this example, I'd like it to find the apparent relation between records containing `Op1 = C` in TableA and `Type = 3000` in TableB.

I could think of apriori in some way, but doesn't seems too practical. what you guys say?

thanks.

Comment: Too poorly defined to be meaningful. Ask enough people, and for any two distinct objects, you'll find a few who insist there is a strong relation between them. Either say which mathematical relationships you're interested in, or just emit "yes" for every instance of the is-correlated problem.

Comment: @Patrick87 I'd dare to say the same of your comment. I can try to improve the question, but non-constructive blabber won't help to move forward. I was trying to make this example as straight forward as possible based on what I know of apriori. i.e. find relations with statistical significance (in this case `C->3000` is more significant than anything). If there's anything else I could put down to clarify or be more specific please ask here, or if you have an possible answer, please post below. thanks.

Comment: @fillipo: It wasn't my intention to be unhelpful. I'm simply pointing out that the relation C->3000 is neither obvious nor obviously significant. Perhaps what you're asking for is this: given two tables, determine whether there exist columns c1 in table1 and c2 in table2 such that c1 and c2 are the same, up to a renaming of the elements. In this case, column "Opt1" in table1 and column "Type" in table2 may indeed be related. If this is what you are going for, I'd be happy to formalize this and suggest an algorithm or two. No hard feelings.

Comment: @Patrick87 Thanks for that, same here. Yes, that seems to be a more specific description. However, I would not want to only look for straight equivalences but also "candidates" for analysis based on something like the "frequency" or "confidence". Maybe the correct text would be "measure whether t1.cx (a column or a combination of table1 columns) approaches t2.cx (a column or a combination of table2 columns)" - does this make more sense or am I making it worse?

Comment: No, you are making it better. What you want is approximate column isomorphism... so columns are the same up to a renaming of elements, possibly with some exceptions. See my answer below to tell whether that's heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a relational data mining problem. I would suggest trying Ross Quinlan's FOIL: http://www.rulequest.com/Personal/

Answer (score 1):

In pseudocode, a naive implementation might look like:

```
  1. for each column c1 in table1
  2.    for each column c2 in table2
  3.      if approximately_isomorphic(c1, c2) then
  4.         emit (c1, c2)

  approximately_isomorphic(c1, c2)
  1. hmap = hash()
  2. for i = 1 to min(|c1|, |c2|) do
  3.    hmap[c1[i]] = c2[i]
  4. if |hmap| - unique_count(c1) < error_margin then return true
  5. else then return false
```

The idea is this: do a pairwise comparison of the elements of each column with each other column. For each pair of columns, construct a hash map linking corresponding elements of the two columns. If the hash map contains the same number of linkings as unique elements of the first column, then you have a perfect isomorphism; if you have a few more, you have a near isomorphism; if you have many more, up to the number of elements in the first column, you have what probably doesn't represent any correlation.

Example on your input:

```
  ID & anything  : perfect isomorphism since all of ID are unique

  Opt1 & ID      : 4 mappings and 3 unique values; not a perfect
                  isomorphism, but not too far away.
  Opt1 & Opt1    : ditto above
  Opt1 & Type    : 3 mappings & 3 unique values, perfect isomorphism

  Opt2 & ID      : 4 mappings & 3 unique values, not a perfect
                  isomorphism, but not too far away
  Opt2 & Opt2    : ditto above
  Opt2 & Type    : ditto above

  Type & anything: perfect isomorphism since all of ID are unique
```

For best results, you might do this procedure both ways - that is, comparing table1 to table2 and then comparing table2 to table1 - to look for bijective mappings. Otherwise, you can be thrown off by trivial cases... all values in the first are different (perfect isomorphism) or all values in the second are the same (perfect isomorphism). Note also that this technique provides a way of ranking, or measuring, how similar or dissimilar columns are.

Is this going in the right direction? By the way, this is O(ijk) where table1 has i columns, table 2 has j columns and each column has k elements. In theory, the best you could do for a method would be O(ik + jk), if you can find correlations without doing pairwise comparisons.